# Помогите со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания в предложении:

**А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм — «Мир инеистых исполинов» — темный, дремучий восток, и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.**

Comment: Вычурно, не по-русски.

Коренные жители "страшного Ётун-хейма" описывают его:

так: "Свирь-матушка в истоке широка, раздольна и открыта без кокетства; берёт начало милая река из моего застенчивого детства",

и

так: "Бродяга к Байкалу подходит, рыбацкую лодку берёт, и тихую песню заводит, о Родине что-то поёт".

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вариант лучше исправить, так как смысловые отношения между распространенным приложением и однородными сказуемыми выражены неясно.

В предложениях с однородными членами при наличии союзов И, ДА=И возможны два варианта решения. Одно тире-дефис ставится при тесной связи приложения и однородного члена (встроенная интонация), а два тире используются  в тех случаях, когда приложение является добавочным сообщением (интонация исключения).

Вариант 1.А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм –  «Мир инеистых исполинов»,  темный, дремучий восток, и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

Вариант 2.  А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм –  «Мир инеистых исполинов»,  темный, дремучий восток – и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в Вашем предложении знаки препинания расставлены верно

Comment: А какую роль выполняет запятая перед И?

Comment: Запятая перед "и" закрывает обособленное приложение

Comment: Обособленные приложения обособляются с двух сторон одинаково: или запятыми, или тире, или присоединяются коротким тире вначале, но запятую после него не ставят.Возможно ещё так: А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм – мир  «инеистых исполинов» ,  темный, дремучий восток - и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

Comment: Такое предложение... Еле нашла это приложение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть варианты:

1.А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм , мир « инеистых исполинов»  –  темный, дремучий восток и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

2.А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм – мир  «инеистых исполинов» ,  темный, дремучий восток, и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

3.А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётун-хейм,    темный, дремучий восток, и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.

«Мир инеистых исполинов» -почему с большой буквы и в кавычках? Это название книги? или чего? Если не название, а просто перифраз, то с маленькой буквы, и можно вообще без кавычек, так как там ВСЕ названия экзотичные,нет смысла выделять это как необычное.

Answer (score 0):

1.*А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётунхейм —  мир инеистых исполинов, темный, дремучий восток —  и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.*

2.*А вот уж там, далее, откуда когда-то пришли великие светлые асы, точно находится, гремит-ворочается страшный Ётунхейм, мир инеистых исполинов, темный, дремучий восток, и кольцом опоясывает все наше людское Среднеземье.*

Обособленные приложения или уточняющие дополнения - называйте, как хотите. В любом случае, эта конструкция выделяется с двух сторон либо запятыми, либо тире.

Comment: Вопрос был на злобу дня, считай, четыре года назад. Автор с тех пор сюда и не заглядывал. Вопрос: слова «называйте, как хотите» кому адресованы?

Comment: "Называйте, как хотите" было адресовано любому, кто читает этот ответ, в том числе автору и всем предыдущим отвечающим на вопрос. Думаете, чтобы ответить кому-то, нужно обязательно заглянуть на профиль к автору, перепроверить всё, разузнать? Я увидела вопрос, просмотрела все ответы, не нашла ни одного, который мне показался бы правильным, и решила написать. Спасибо, в следующий раз буду смотреть на дату.